# Trigger 'cron' do not working in apscheduler 3 while 'interval' works fine

Tags: python, triggers, cron, apscheduler

I am trying to use package `apscheduler` 3.1.0 to run a python job every day at the same time. But it seems do not run the job correctly. Then I find that even using the simplest case, the trigger "interval" can work, but "cron" won't. When run the following code in python 2.7.11, it seems running, but did not print anything.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def job_function():
    print "Hello World"

sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', second = '*/2')
sched.start()
```

When replacing

`sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', second = '*/2')`

to

`sched.add_job(job_function, 'interval', seconds = 2)`, it works fine.

I already update the setuptools to 20.6.7. Does anybody know what is wrong?